# Merging two sql queries columns into one

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, dataset

I have two queries that return:

Query 1

```
ClassName1  Students1   Teachers1
    A1      30          3
    A2      20          3
    A3      35          4
```

Query 2

```
ClassName2  Students2   Teachers2
    A1      20          3
    A2      22          3
    A3      20          4
```

Result

```
ClassName1  Students1   Teachers1   ClassName2  Students2   Teachers2
A1          30          3           A1          20          3
A2          20          3           A2          22          3
A3          35          4           A3          20          4
```

I would like to merge the two dataset into one by columns. SQL 2008

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you ensuring that both queries will return the same number of rows and that there will always be a perfect 1:1 relationship? Could you show the queries instead of the results, because if these are coming from the same table, there is probably a more straightforward solution...

Comment: Yes indeed both queries will show same numbers of rows

Answer (score 2):

You would normally do this with a `join`:

```
select q1.*, q2.*
from (query1) q1 join
     (query2) q2
     on q1.ClassName1 = q2.ClassName2;
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks i worked this out using this :

**/***********Join **************

select emp.EmpID,emp.FirstName ,emp.LastName,sod.EmpID,sod.HireDate from  Employee as emp

join

(
select emp2.EmpID,emp2.HireDate from  Employee as emp2

--where emp.EmpID=emp2.EmpID

) sod

on sod.EmpID=emp.EmpID

**/***********cross Apply **************

select emp.EmpID,emp.FirstName ,emp.LastName,sod.EmpID,sod.HireDate from  Employee as emp

cross apply

(
select emp2.EmpID,emp2.HireDate from  Employee as emp2

where emp.EmpID=emp2.EmpID

) as sod

Any other ideas will be great